# Deleting firebase entry node Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I added a list of countries to firebase from a listview and now im trying to delete nodes seperately by list view item click.

That list is now shown in a listview which i want that when i click on a particular country it gets removed.  So far i have done:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String Country =(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            showPopUp(Country);
        }
    });
```

That got the Country that i press on. In the popup menu method i have:

```
public void showPopUp(final String cntry) {

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.id));
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.Delete:



                    // Delete from Firebase

                    dref.child(cntry).removeValue();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cntry,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.Goback:

                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }


        }

    });
```

Although i think i need to remove the key not the child from firebase in my case. How should i implement this please?

Note: I added the countries from API to list view by:

```
 DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourite_countries_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstViewFavCountries);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    list.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

https://gyazo.com/705654bde00d245bed57bfd45f1a2f67 the link of database

Comment: please show your `listView` implementation (how do you populate the data to the `listView`)

Comment: post edited again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the key somewhere, call `dataSnapshot.getKey()` to get the key.

First of all, create a new list for the keys

```
ArrayList<String> listKey = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then add the key to the list

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        list.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));
        listKey.add(dsp.getKey());
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Finally, in your `onItemClick` method, get the key from the list based on the `position` then pass the string to the deletion method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
    String CountryKey = listKey.get(position);
    showPopUp(CountryKey);
}
```

Then to delete the value

```
dref.child("Countries").child(cntry).removeValue();
```

Comment: and deletion method will include : myref.removeValue(); ?

Comment: yes, that method is correct already `dref.child(cntry).removeValue();`. You don't have to do anything inside `showPopUp()`

Comment: please just update your code in your question @GlenMicallef

Comment: what work and what do not work? have you successfully populate the data from the database to the listview before? because I notice something weird with the database reference

Comment: The population into the list view is correct and the toast showing the key of each country pressed is also shown correctly. I think there is something in dref.child(cntry).removeValue(); as the record remains there but the key is passed

Comment: @GlenMicallef ah, I think I get it. Can you post your full database structure from the root? You don't need to show everything, at least I know the structure.

Comment: edited. Maybe it has something to do with specifying the root name

Comment: @GlenMicallef I have updated my answer. By the way, is the listview only populate childs from `/Countries`? If that so, you can use `ValueEventListener` instead at `/Countries` or can you explain why do you want to use `ChildEventListener` at the root?

Comment: It worked !! All i did was dref.child("Countries").child(cntry).removeValue();

Comment: Ofcourse ! Thanks alot for your time and help! :) All i have to do now is make it so that the listview refreshes automatically when a record gets deleted